# Pygame window keeps scales weirdly

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason when ever I make a program with pygame, the window is bigger then I make it but all the coordinates are okay and it's been annoying me a lot. Can anyone help with this?

Here is a part of code I use to test it:

```
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode() # Makes a window the size of the screen
print(f'Window size: {WIN.get_size()}\nScreen size: {pygame.display.list_modes()[0]}') # Displays window size and screen size
```

Here is the output:

```
Window size: (1536, 864)
Screen size: (1920, 1080)
```

Edit: putting (1536, 864) doesn't work

Comment: Are you using display scaling in your desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

replace `WIN = pygame.display.set_mode()` with `WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((1536, 864))`  . So what I think is the problem is that the screen's size is not specified. Hence the weird scaling.